# restrict number of filter results on Google Sheets with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter

I want the user to be able to rstrict the number of shown results in a table filtered per the user's decision.

The user enters the max results to show in cell A1.
The table (with or without fitered rows) is from row 2 to the last row (row 2 is headers).

Currently, I use `.showRows()` as follows:
`sheet.showRows(3,sheet.getRange('A1').getValue());`

The issue with this is that it takes also the filtered out rows into consideration.

For example, if the user want to see 5 result and rows 4-6 are filtred out- the spreadsheet will show only 2 rows (3 and 7), when it is supposed to show 5 rows (3 and 7-10).

How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate rows in the sheet and use [Sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#isrowhiddenbyfilterrowposition) to count rows that are *not* hidden until you have found a sufficient number of unfiltered rows, then hide the rows below that with [Sheet.hideRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hiderowsrowindex,-numrows).

Comment: Thank you. I was hopping there was a way I did not think about that can iterate only on the rows not hidden by filter. In case of hundreds of hidden rows your suggestion will be pretty slow :\

Comment: Star the issue [Add methods to Sheet and/or Range to get all of the hidden rows/columns at once](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128600464) if you would like Google to implement a faster method.